# Is my site vulnerable to a XSS attack if it has no back-end code?

Tags: javascript, html, database, sanitization

I have a website where I want people to be able to input a number into an input box (tag iteration of `sel`) and it is taken and multiplied with a preset value stored in a tag with the class "`value`" whose class iteration is also `sel`.

Vague layout of what I have:

```
function multiply() {
  if(!Number.isInteger(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[sel].value)) sel = undefined;
  else {
    document.getElementById('value').textContent =
      parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName('value')[sel].value) * 
      parseInt(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[sel].value);
  }
}
```

I have no back-end code and everything is handled through JavaScript. Would this handling of inputs cause any issues/vulnerabilities?

I've tried to find other resources on this issue, but nothing has given me a straight answer on the main question of if there are any server or user vulnerabilities when you don't use a database and handle everything with JavaScript.

Comment: Even if it was, what damage can be done on a site that doesn't have a database or store user data?

Comment: XSS is intended to expose back-end part via code injection (e.g. steal session). But if there is no back-end, there is nothing to steal. I can change what ever I want in opened HTML document - everything is unsafe here, but it's on my computer, so no damage here

Comment: If you have no backend, you might not be vulnerable to pure XSS, but script injection on a public device, you may be vulnerable that way...if you have any form of login/session handling or are not hosting as pure html/js the server you are hosted on may be vulnerable.  If you are self-hosting - google how to harden your setup, otherwise you can assume you are safe-ish.

Comment: In your case with no database, you are only concerned with two attacks. Reflected XSS and DOM based XSS. With Reflected, so long as you don't process url query parameters and write them to the DOM nobody can construct a malicious link. For example a script in the url that forms part of a bot, or makes requests to child pornography sites etc. Then your customers would not be happy!  With DOM based, you are correctly using  `textContent` to write back to the DOM so you are safe there. This question is more for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You've used `Element.textContent = ..` so, no, there is not XSS vulnerability. If you've used something like `Element.innerHTML = ..` there could be a vulnerability but, in this case, you're definitely setting that to a **Number**.